# Problems with postgres database in redmine after change in password

Tags: postgresql, redmine

First, I'm a total newbie and I guess that's why this error occurred in the first place.
A colleague of mine stopped working and so I had to take over administrative stuff as the `redmine` we use and making backups.
So I wanted to schedule these backups automatically. Somewhere on the way I changed `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf` for user postgres (that's the one for the redmine database.
from `local all postgress peer` to `local all postgress trust` so I could run a shell program in crontab. This worked but then redmine doesn't work anymore. I get this:

> FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" FATAL:
>   password authentication failed for user "postgres" (PG::Error)

On this the error site for redmine. I changed everything back and restarted everything, but it did't work. 
Then I used an older backup to restore but still.
So, now I have no idea whats wrong. Maybe someone can help me.
Thanks.
Barbara

Comment: can you post the contents of your `pg_hba.conf` file, excluding the comments?

Comment: I will post it as soon as I am back at work (Firday or Thursday)
But it is now the version from before I made the changes.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to restart (or `pg_ctl reload`) PostgreSQL after changing `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: I've restarted it as well as my apache server.

Comment: It's working again. It was just the password I've changed. And first I forgot the ';' at the end for changing the password. Thanks to all of you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because I've changed the password of the postgres user in ubuntu. I did not know at the moment that they are connected. I always got a password promt but I didn't know it (my colleague at least didn't tell me one) I've tried to change it in the data base as well with

```
ALTER USER Postgres WITH PASSWORD 'newpassword';
```

Would it be enough to reinstall the database and use an old backup?